# How to test a custom validator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, validation, activemodel

I have the following validator:

```
# Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-validators
# app/validators/email_validator.rb

class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(object, attribute, value)
    unless value =~ /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i
      object.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not formatted properly") 
    end
  end
end
```

I would like to be able to test this in RSpec inside of my lib directory.  The problem so far is I am not sure how to initialize an `EachValidator`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here's a quick spec I knocked up for that file and it works well.  I think the stubbing could probably be cleaned up, but hopefully this will be enough to get you started.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'EmailValidator' do

  before(:each) do
    @validator = EmailValidator.new({:attributes => {}})
    @mock = mock('model')
    @mock.stub('errors').and_return([])
    @mock.errors.stub('[]').and_return({})
    @mock.errors[].stub('<<')
  end

  it 'should validate valid address' do
    @mock.should_not_receive('errors')    
    @validator.validate_each(@mock, 'email', 'test@test.com')
  end

  it 'should validate invalid address' do
    @mock.errors[].should_receive('<<')
    @validator.validate_each(@mock, 'email', 'notvalid')
  end  
end
```

Comment: Works great.  Didn't know about mock('model') ill try to learn more about that.

Comment: http://rspec.info/documentation/mocks/  That is the old RSpec documentation, but the mock constructor remains the same.  model is just an identifier for the mock.

Comment: You can also do it functionally with factories.

Comment: I think a factory is overkill. We just want an otherwise empty class to contain the errors array.

Comment: It works great! I just did a different stub: @model = mock('model', errors: ActiveModel::Errors.new({}))

Comment: On newer versions of Rails (I'm using 4.1) you'll need to specify some attributes to your validator to avoid getting an ArgumentError - it doesn't matter what you pass in as long as the attributes aren't empty, so something like `@validator = EmailValidator.new({:attributes => { :foo => :bar }})` will do the trick.

Answer (score 79):

I am not a huge fan of the other approach because it ties the test too close to the implementation. Also, it's fairly hard to follow. This is the approach I ultimately use. Please keep in mind that this is a gross oversimplification of what my validator actually did... just wanted to demonstrate it more simply. There are definitely optimizations to be made

```
class OmniauthValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if !record.omniauth_provider.nil? && !%w(facebook github).include?(record.omniauth_provider)
      record.errors[:omniauth_provider] << 'Invalid omniauth provider'
    end
  end
end
```

Associated Spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

class Validatable
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_with OmniauthValidator
  attr_accessor  :omniauth_provider
end

describe OmniauthValidator do
  subject { Validatable.new }

  context 'without provider' do
    it 'is valid' do
      expect(subject).to be_valid
    end
  end

  context 'with valid provider' do
    it 'is valid' do
      subject.stubs(omniauth_provider: 'facebook')

      expect(subject).to be_valid
    end
  end

  context 'with unused provider' do
    it 'is invalid' do
      subject.stubs(omniauth_provider: 'twitter')

      expect(subject).not_to be_valid
      expect(subject).to have(1).error_on(:omniauth_provider)
    end
  end
end
```

Basically my approach is to create a fake object "Validatable" so that we can actually test the results on it rather than have expectations for each part of the implementation

Comment: I like this because I'm a fan of testing validation through the ActiveModel::Validations module. Otherwise you're tying the test to ActiveModel's implementation which is fragile.

Comment: With Rails 4.1.6, I got ":attributes cannot be blank" until I changed the validates_with call to include the attribute name, e.g. `validates_with OmniauthValidator, attributes: 'omniauth_provider'`

Comment: With Rails 4.1.7, I was able to get around the ":attribute cannot be blank" error with `validates :omniauth_provider, omniauth: true`

Comment: Hey, I would love to see that optimizations! There is not much documentation about validation testing out there.

Comment: Nice, I think this is a much cleaner solution than the accepted answer.

Comment: In rspec 3+ (I think is when it changed) you need the rspec-collection_matchers gem to use have(1).error_on.

Answer (score 21):

I would recommend creating an anonymous class for testing purposes such as:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'active_model'
require 'email_validator'

RSpec.describe EmailValidator do
  subject do
    Class.new do
      include ActiveModel::Validations    
      attr_accessor :email
      validates :email, email: true
    end.new
  end

  describe 'empty email addresses' do
    ['', nil].each do |email_address|
      describe "when email address is #{email_address}" do
        it "does not add an error" do
          subject.email = email_address
          subject.validate
          expect(subject.errors[:email]).not_to include 'is not a valid email address'
        end
      end
    end
  end

  describe 'invalid email addresses' do
    ['nope', '@', 'foo@bar.com.', '.', ' '].each do |email_address|
      describe "when email address is #{email_address}" do

        it "adds an error" do
          subject.email = email_address
          subject.validate
          expect(subject.errors[:email]).to include 'is not a valid email address'
        end
      end
    end
  end

  describe 'valid email addresses' do
    ['foo@bar.com', 'foo@bar.bar.co'].each do |email_address|
      describe "when email address is #{email_address}" do
        it "does not add an error" do
          subject.email = email_address
          subject.validate
          expect(subject.errors[:email]).not_to include 'is not a valid email address'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This will prevent hardcoded classes such as `Validatable`, which could be referenced in multiple specs, resulting in unexpected and hard to debug behavior due to interactions between unrelated validations, which you are trying to test in isolation.

Comment: Great answer. In Rails 6 I had to provide a `model_name` method for ActiveRecord. Inside the Class.new block I added a method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14431888/1038034):
`def self.model_name
   ActiveModel::Name.new(self, nil, 'temp')
end`

Answer (score 6):

Inspired by @Gazler's answer I came up with the following; mocking the model, but using `ActiveModel::Errors` as errors object. This slims down the mocking quite a lot.

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe EmailValidator, type: :validator do
  subject { EmailValidator.new(attributes: { any: true }) }

  describe '#validate_each' do
    let(:errors) { ActiveModel::Errors.new(OpenStruct.new) }
    let(:record) {
      instance_double(ActiveModel::Validations, errors: errors)
    }

    context 'valid email' do
      it 'does not increase error count' do
        expect {
          subject.validate_each(record, :email, 'test@example.com')
        }.to_not change(errors, :count)
      end
    end

    context 'invalid email' do
      it 'increases the error count' do
        expect {
          subject.validate_each(record, :email, 'fakeemail')
        }.to change(errors, :count)
      end

      it 'has the correct error message' do
        expect {
          subject.validate_each(record, :email, 'fakeemail')
        }.to change { errors.first }.to [:email, 'is not an email']
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is the nice answer for 2020 (_rspec-rails_ `4.0`).

Answer (score 4):

One more example, with extending an object instead of creating new class in the spec. **BitcoinAddressValidator** is a custom validator here.

```
require 'rails_helper'

module BitcoinAddressTest
  def self.extended(parent)
    class << parent
      include ActiveModel::Validations
      attr_accessor :address
      validates :address, bitcoin_address: true
    end
  end
end

describe BitcoinAddressValidator do
  subject(:model) { Object.new.extend(BitcoinAddressTest) }

  it 'has invalid bitcoin address' do
    model.address = 'invalid-bitcoin-address'
    expect(model.valid?).to be_falsey
    expect(model.errors[:address].size).to eq(1)
  end

  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Using Neals great example as a basis I came up with the following (for Rails and RSpec 3).

```
# /spec/lib/slug_validator_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

class Validatable
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :slug

  validates :slug, slug: true
end

RSpec.describe SlugValidator do
  subject { Validatable.new(slug: slug) }

  context 'when the slug is valid' do
    let(:slug) { 'valid' }

    it { is_expected.to be_valid }
  end

  context 'when the slug is less than the minimum allowable length' do
    let(:slug) { 'v' }

    it { is_expected.to_not be_valid }
  end

  context 'when the slug is greater than the maximum allowable length' do
    let(:slug) { 'v' * 64 }

    it { is_expected.to_not be_valid }
  end

  context 'when the slug contains invalid characters' do
    let(:slug) { '*' }

    it { is_expected.to_not be_valid }
  end

  context 'when the slug is a reserved word' do
    let(:slug) { 'blog' }

    it { is_expected.to_not be_valid }
  end
end
```

Comment: You don't need to include `ActiveModel::Model`, also it might be better to create an anonymous class such as `subject { Class.new { include ActiveModel::Validations; attr_accessor :slug; validate :slug, slug: true }.new }`

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible to not use stubs I would prefer this way:

```rb
require "rails_helper"

describe EmailValidator do
  let(:user) { build(:user, email: email) } # let's use any real model
  let(:validator) { described_class.new(attributes: [:email]) } # validate email field

  subject { validator.validate(user) }

  context "valid email" do
    let(:email) { "person@mail.com" }

    it "should be valid" do
      # with this expectation we isolate specific validator we test
      # and avoid leaking of other validator errors rather than with `user.valid?`
      expect { subject }.to_not change { user.errors.count } 
      expect(user.errors[:email]).to be_blank
    end
  end

  context "ivalid email" do
    let(:email) { "invalid.com" }

    it "should be invalid" do
      expect { subject }.to change { user.errors.count }
      # Here we can check message
      expect(user.errors[:email]).to be_present
      expect(user.errors[:email].join(" ")).to include("Email is invalid")
    end
  end
end
```