# ActiveModel::Validations on anonymous class

Tags: ruby, activemodel

I'm working on a small DataMapper-like ODM project, and I'm trying to make use of the `ActiveModel::Validations` component. However, I ran into a problem while writing tests - I'm using anonymous classes to construct my test schemas, however when it comes to running the validators, the `ActiveModel::Name` class is throwing an error:
`Class name cannot be blank. You need to supply a name argument when anonymous class given`

Here's a simple code example to reproduce:

```
require 'active_model'

book_class = Class.new do
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  validates_presence_of :title

  def title; ""; end # This will fail validation
end

book_class.new.valid? # => throws error
```

The exception is only raised when there's a failed validator - I'm guessing the problem happens when it tries to construct the validation error message. So my question is:

- I did a lot of searching, but couldn't find anyone trying to do something similar. Is this simply not possible with ActiveModel, or is there a workaround I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

ActiveModel tries to get the model name (as you see here) when setting up the error messages. The quickest way to get around it (short of giving your anonymous class a name), is to give your class a class method `model_name` that returns an instance of `ActiveModel::Name`.

for example

```
require 'active_model'

book_class = Class.new do
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  def self.model_name
    ActiveModel::Name.new(self, nil, "temp")
  end
  validates_presence_of :title

  def title; ""; end # This will fail validation
end

book_class.new.valid? # => no error
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted! I noticed that `ActiveModel::Name` can take a class name as an argument, but didn't spot that I can return my own instance via `self.model_name`. Another reason not to program late at night... :P

Comment: Why return an instance of `ActiveModel::Name` rather than a plain string from `.model_name`?

Comment: This was 2 years ago, but IIRC, the validation process expects (expected?) an instance of ActiveModel::Name from that method.

Answer (score 14):

The error is being thrown in the initialize function of `ActiveModel::Name` [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8742bc9d5e030b4ac6119d61a163ba72c2e7e380/activemodel/lib/active_model/naming.rb#L148).

```
module ActiveModel
  class Name
    def initialize(klass, namespace = nil, name = nil)
      @name = name || klass.name

      raise ArgumentError, "Class name cannot be blank. You need to supply a name argument when anonymous class given" if @name.blank?       
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

So rather than defining a class method `model_name` that returns an `ActiveModel::Name`, you can define a class method `name` that returns a `String`.

```
require 'active_model'

book_class = Class.new do
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_presence_of :title

  def self.name
    "Book"
  end

  def title; ""; end # This will fail validation
end

book_class.new.valid? # => false
```

Comment: This is essentially because `Class.new.name #=> nil`, so either passing `name` to ActiveModel::Name or defining a name method on the class works.