# Testing custom validators with Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, unit-testing, minitest, custom-validators

I have multiple models with email validation. Therefore I've extracted the validation into a custom validator. I dit this by following the tutorial of the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators).

```
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    unless value =~ /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not an email")
    end
  end
end
```

So far, so good. But since I've extracted the functionality of email validation into it's own scope I also want to test it separately. I don't want to add the same email format tests to every model.

I found another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744171/how-to-test-a-custom-validator) which also asked the same but for RSpec. But since I haven't worked with stubs and mocks yet, I don't know how to port the tests to Minitest tests. I haven't found any resources which test custom validators with Minitest.

Does anybody know how to write such tests for custom validators in Minitest (not using specs!)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What (I think) you are asking for here is testing this validator in **isolation**. This means that it will be tested once, in an isolated test, which will do exactly what you said:

> I don't want to add the same email format tests to every model.

The approach I would take here is to create just a test class in a test file, mix-in the `ActiveRecord::Validations` module and test the class itself.

```
# test_file.rb
require 'test_helper'

class EmailValidatable
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_with EmailValidator
  attr_accessor  :email
end

class EmailValidatorTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_invalidates_object_for_invalid_email
    obj = EmailValidatable.new
    obj.email = "invalidemail"
    refute obj.valid?
  end

  def test_adds_error_for_invalid_email
    obj = EmailValidatable.new
    obj.email = "invalidemail"
    refute_nil obj.errors[:email]
  end

  def test_adds_no_errors_for_valid_email
    obj = EmailValidatable.new
    obj.email = "valid@email.com"
    assert_nil obj.errors[:email]
    assert obj.valid?
  end
end
```

I haven't tested the code above, but I think that it should give you an idea/direction.

HTH

Comment: This is exactly what I've search for. I never thought about creating a new class and test it from there. I was always looking for a way on how to testing it directly. But this looks even better! Thanks!

Comment: Great, I am happy I helped. Could you pate(bin) the full test of yours? Thanks :)

Comment: Hi @Ile! I've added my implemented solution as answer. Thank you again!

Answer (score 4):

Here's my implemented solution based on the answer of Ile Eftimov:

```
require 'test_helper'

class EmailValidatable
    include ActiveModel::Validations
    attr_accessor :email

    validates :email, email: true
end

class EmailValidatorTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
    invalid_email_addresses = ['invalid email@example.com', 'invalid@ example.com', 'invalid@@example.com', 'invalid', 'invalid@example']

    def obj; @obj ||= EmailValidatable.new; end

    test 'should invalidate email address' do
        invalid_email_addresses.each do |email|
            obj.email = email
            assert_not obj.valid?
        end
    end

    test 'should add error for invalid email' do
        invalid_email_addresses.each do |email|
            obj.email = email
            obj.valid?
            assert_equal I18n.t('errors.messages.not_an_email_address'), obj.errors[:email][0], "no error message for invalid email address \"#{email}\""
        end
    end

    test 'should validate email address' do
        obj.email = FFaker::Internet.email
        assert obj.valid?
    end

    test 'should add no error for valid email' do
        obj.email = FFaker::Internet.email
        assert obj.errors[:email].blank?
    end
end
```

Really cool solution and is also usable for other tests.