# What is the 'end.new' in Ruby for? Why not just use 'end' on it's own

Tags: ruby

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744171/how-to-test-a-custom-validator) and the answer from @Kris has the line:

```
end.new
```

here:

```
  subject do
    Class.new do
      include ActiveModel::Validations    
      attr_accessor :email
      validates :email, email: true
    end.new
  end
```

I have not seen that before and cannot find other examples nor explanations.

Why not just 'end' on it's own, like this:

```
  subject do
    Class.new do
      include ActiveModel::Validations    
      attr_accessor :email
      validates :email, email: true
    end
  end
```

What is the difference?

Comment: `Class.new` will return a class. `Class.new.new` will return an instance of that class.

Comment: @ndnenkov Oh that's cool, thanks, grokked it immediately with your comment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to understand that you can chain statements on `end`, for example

```
[1,2,3,4,5].select do |num|
  i % 2 == 0
end.map do |num|
  "#{num} is even"
end.each do |str|
  puts str
end
```

Next, to understand your example you need to understand what is an "anonymous" class.

You can define this class normally instead:

```
class MyClass
  include ActiveModel::Validations    
  attr_accessor :email
  validates :email, email: true
end
```

and you will have defined a *global* `MyClass` variable that refers to the *class*. Of course, you can call `MyClass.new` to get an instance.

The anomymous class block `Class.new do` is the same thing but it doesn't define a global identifer for the class. Instead, to get a handle on the class you must assign a variable to the result of the `Class.new do .. end` expression.

So, if you understand that `Class.new do ... end` returns a class, and you can call `.new` on any class, then you can do something like the code in your question:

```
klass = Class.new { def foo; "bar"; end }
klass.new.foo # => "bar"

# or ...
Class.new { def foo; "bar"; end }.new.foo # => "bar"
```

`do ... end` being the multiline version of `{}` to define a block